# Objective-C or Cocoa First

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am new to Mac/iOS development. I am coming over from C# .net. My question is should I read on Objective-C first or Cocoa? I don't want to buy two books and start reading one and find out I should have only got one book and read it.
Thanks
Curtis

Comment: Cocoa framework is written in Objective C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as how the Cocoa frameworks were built with Objective-C, learning the language is the logical first step.

Comment: …which you'll most likely do using code practices utilizing instances of NSObject (or its subclasses), by which you're basically using Cocoa. There's pretty much no sane way of learning one without the other. It's kind of like with the chicken and the egg.

Comment: The OP should *at least* have a firm handle on the syntax of the language first. I believe that a lot of the questions that crop up on this site stem from people attempting to learn Cocoa without understanding the foundation that it is built on.

Comment: Absolutely right, Mark. What I meant was that it's kind of impossible to learn the english language (or Objective-C) without also using (and by that learning) english words (or classes such as NSObject, etc a.k.a Cocoa). You can learn the abstract concepts of the english language, (as in grammar), but it won't bring you anywhere near being able to actually write something with it unless you also learn to use english words. Didn't mean to object your answer in any way, anyway. ;)

Comment: I believe this answer may be misleading to the OP. Learning ObjC without Cocoa is like learning C# without .NET. While it is technically true that you will have to learn a little ObjC first, it will be about 5 minutes into your first tutorial program when you need to use Cocoa.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to become fluent in the language, to the point of exchanging implementations and dispatching blocks like nobody's business, all before you learn the frameworks. Indeed, such an undertaking would be folly.

At the same time, you can't learn Cocoa without a firm grasp of OOP, dynamic dispatch (messaging), MVC, and other important concepts. Some of these underlie Objective-C, some are part of Objective-C, and some are separate from Objective-C.

I say start learning those concepts, including the basic portions of the language, and then pick up the framework before you get too far into it. Like Regexident said in their comment on one of the other answers, you pretty much can't practice Objective-C without using Cocoa anyway, so it won't be long before you need to start into the framework to in order to practice the language—at which point you'll be practicing with both.

Relevant Apple documentation:

- [Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/)
- [Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/)
- [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/)
- [The (full, gory details of the) Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/)

If you don't already know C, start there. As with Objective-C, you don't need to become a full-blown C guru, but you do need to understand pointers, declarations vs. statements, how function calls work, the differences between the primitive types, and other basic concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is just a superset of C. All the Cocoa books that I've seen introduce Objective-C in the first part and then go on to describe how to use the frameworks. I'd recommend just getting a Cocoa book, just leaf through it and make sure the Objective-C primer in it is meaty enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a lot of good information in the various answers here (especially @Peter Hosey's), but I do want to make sure we're not confusing the OP.

You can't practically learn ObjC without learning Cocoa today. It's like learning C# without learning .NET. You absolutely should focus very early on the patterns and underlying concepts of Cocoa (like MVC, as PH notes). But you'll get that best by working through things that teach you practical iOS or Mac development techniques rather than working through something that tries to provide a more "pure ObjC" experience such as writing command-line apps (though even Foundation is part of Cocoa, so even then you can't escape it).

The key lesson here is that I recommend new students focus on resources that teach them the whole process they need to develop for iOS or OS X. It's worth learning Xcode, ObjC, and Cocoa(Touch) together, along with MVC, target/selector, and the other critical patterns, rather than trying to take them one at a time.

PH is absolutely correct that you don't need to learn *all* of ObjC in one go. You can do a lot of development and never use blocks or KVO for instance. (That may change in future versions of iOS, but it's still true today.)